# Как удалить стили в футере WP?

Tags: css, wordpress

В футере сайта генерируется такие стили, как их удалить?

```
    <style id='wp-block-heading-inline-css' type='text/css'>
    h1.has-background,h2.has-background,h3.has-background,h4.has-background,h5.has-background,h6.has-background{padding:1.25em 2.375em}
    </style>
    
    <style id='wp-block-list-inline-css' type='text/css'>
    ol,ul{box-sizing:border-box}ol.has-background,ul.has-background{padding:1.25em 2.375em}
    </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    add_filter( 'styles_inline_size_limit', '__return_zero' );
```

добавить в functions.php вашей активной темы

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Постарайтесь делать ваши ответы более развёрнутыми и добавлять в них больше объяснения. Подробнее [в справке](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Ответ можно отредактировать кнопкой «[править](//ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1485225/edit)»